# How to move a proxy value from package.json to setupProxy.js in CRA v2?

Tags: reactjs, cors, create-react-app, package.json

Since recently released CRA (Create React App) v2 it's now possible to move proxy settings from `package.json` to `setupProxy.js`. My question is a simple one: how should my `setupProxy.js` look like if I simply want to always use `http://127.0.0.1:5000`? I need this because if everything works correctly (no luck so far) I can replace it with variable from `.env` files for dev/prod environments.
But so far I only get either a or b:

a) CORS errors

b) my app's `index.html` is returned as a result of http request

Here's an example of one of the versions of setupProxy.js I tried:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use('/', proxy({target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000', changeOrigin: true}));
  app.use('/*', proxy({target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000', changeOrigin: true}));
  app.use(proxy({'/', target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000', changeOrigin: true}));
  app.use(proxy({'/*', target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000', changeOrigin: true}));
};
```

I tried various versions of `app.use` line, I just posted several examples here.

I usually tried with one `app.use` line at a time, but also with multiple lines.

I restarted react app everytime I changed the file.

I also tried using `process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASEURL` instead of `'http://127.0.0.1:5000'` which is my final goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly using `setupProxy.js` is only good for local development, but I also needed for it to work on the live/deployed server, too, so I ended up not using `setupProxy.js` at all - I saved different backend URLs as `REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASEURL` variable in different `.env` files (loclahost url in `.env.development` file and remote url in `.env.production` file) and replaced all the occurrences in the frontend JavaScript code to use `process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASEURL`.

Answer (score 0):

so try

```
app.use(proxy('/**', { target:'http://127.0.0.1:5000', changeOrigin: true }))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - this looks like it could be a good answer if **why it works** was explained!